# Start a local script from server on Roblox studio

Tags: lua, roblox

I have a map which I would like to load in the workspace. The map also comes with its own local scripts. However, I don't know where to place them in the player. Maybe I can put them in StarterPlayerScripts and then start them from the server(if Roblox studio has such a functionality).

Answer (score 1):

You can start the local script by simply changing his localscript.Disabled bool value, just change their disabled value to false inside properties when you create them. Example:

```
localscript.Disabled = true
--Disables localscript
--------------------------------------
localscript.Disabled = false
--Enables it
```

Answer (score 0):

Check inside the `LocalScript` for any code statements of `script.Parent` and put the `LocalScript` inside whatever the Parent is.